# Cannot understand why this works (coalesce)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @result varchar(max)

SELECT    
    @result = coalesce(@result + ',', '') + Mobile
FROM    
    VMembers
WHERE   
    CommitteesID = 45
```

I think if it is checking for null of Mobile, it should be

```
DECLARE @result varchar(max)

SELECT    
    @result = @result + ISNULL(Mobile + ',', '')
FROM    
    VMembers
WHERE   
    CommitteesID = 45
```

But this always yields `@result = NULL`. I don't understand why the first one works while the second one is not working.

Comment: @result is initially NULL. Adding sth to NULL yields always a NULL

Comment: `@result = @result + ISNULL(Mobile + ',', '')` : NULL + any string = null but in above case it is not the same.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos so, why the first one is working

Comment: Because the first one makes use of coalesce, which effectively replaces the null value of @result

Comment: If you want to concatenate (potential) `NULL` values with another string, you can use the `concat` function. It replaces a `null` with '' (empty string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version is checking `@result` for `NULL`, which is correct because it starts off as `NULL`.  Your version would always return NULL, because `@result` starts out as `NULL`.

The code is not checking `Mobile` for `NULL`.

You could also initialize the value by doing:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(max) = '';

SELECT    @result = @result + ',' + Mobile
FROM    VMembers
WHERE   CommitteesID=45
```

However, that would put an unnecessary comma at the beginning of the string.

Let me note:  this is not my preferred method for doing string aggregation, but it does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

None of your queries ever initialises @result, which means that @result has the value NULL before the query starts.

In the first query, this is handled by @result being inside the `COALESCE` statement, which outputs '' when @result is NULL. This doesn't happen in the 2nd query, so the output will always be NULL (remember that when concatenating strings, NULL + 'whatever' always equals NULL).